# Is it possible to set a parameterized build or pass an environment variable via a hudson build trigger?

Tags: triggers, hudson

I'd like to use the IM plugin or maybe an email trigger to initiate a build.  The job/build needs one parameter that I would have to set with the trigger mechanism.

In looking at the jabber/IM plugin it does not look like this is possible (the parameter part)

Has anyone solved this in some way?  Should I use some other mechanism?

The build server is not on a public/internet facing machine - it is within our internal network.  Current builds are triggered by an SCM/SVN commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I would use an URL to trigger the build. See [Parameterized Builds](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Build). The URL is

  ```
   http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER=Value
  ```
- You can also check into the [Remote Access API](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API) for other options.
- On the [Building a Software Project](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project) you can see examples on how to configure an **email trigger**. Just replace the URL with the one from the [Parameterized Builds](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Build) page.

---

**EDIT:** I just looked up the Jabber and IM Plugins. They both support parametrized builds. Jabber since 1.9 which corresponds to IM 1.7. The issue is logged in Hudson's JIRA under [Hudson-5058](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5058). Please don't ask me how you actually need to configure the parameters; I couldn't find any documentation for that. But you have a look at the changes made for the issue (the links to the code changes can be found in [Hudson-5058](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5058)).

Comment: The problem with this is that one needs access to the build machine's network for this to work - I don't have that luxury - I want to trigger from outside our network.

Comment: Check the email trigger description. You basically set up an email account that is watched for incoming mails. The mail gets analysed for the paramter(s) and you then use the remote API to trigger the build from inside of your network.

Comment: Accepted the answer for the edit with the jabber/IM plugins.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

After some initial testing I am confident that I have a solution:

- installed the IM plugin
- installed the jabber plugin
- set up a gmail/google chat account for my hudson service

The jabber plugin sends responses so if you do something wrong it is fairly easy to get the right commands, etc.  The only caveat so far is that I don't know how to trigger a build with a name that has a space in it or to set an env var/parameter with a value that has a space in it.  No big deal for either of those - I an work around them. (for now)

I chose the jabber method because I could not figure out how to set up email trigger and the jabber was pretty painless.

Here is the help that the hudson plugin sends back after a !help command is sent to it.

> Available commands:
>
> abort  - specify which job to
>   abort
>
> alias [ []] - defines
>   a new alias, deletes one or lists all
>   existing aliases
>
> botsnack [] - om nom nom
>
> build  [now|[s|m|h]]
>   [=]* - schedule a
>   job build, with standard, custom or no
>   quiet period
>
> comment    -
>   adds a description to a build
>
> h [|-v ] - show the health
>   of a specific job, jobs in a view or
>   all jobs
>
> health [|-v ] - show the
>   health of a specific job, jobs in a
>   view or all jobs
>
> jobs [|-v ] - show the
>   status of a specific job, jobs in a
>   view or all jobs
>
> q - show the state of the build queue
>
> queue - show the state of the build
>   queue
>
> s [|-v ] - show the status
>   of a specific job, jobs in a view or
>   all jobs
>
> schedule  [now|[s|m|h]]
>   [=]* - schedule a
>   job build, with standard, custom or no
>   quiet period
>
> status [|-v ] - show the
>   status of a specific job, jobs in a
>   view or all jobs
>
> testresult [|-v ] - show
>   the test results of a specific job,
>   jobs in a view or all jobs
>
> userstat  - prints
>   information about a Hudson user

Thanks for the help Peter.